# Why does ugettext_lazy in rest_auth return a strange value?

Tags: django

I tried to response using ugettext_lazy with this code.

```py
return Response({"detail": _("New password has been saved.")})
```

And the response value I expected is `{"detail": "New password has been saved."`

But the actual return value is

```
{
    "detail": [
        "N",
        "e",
        "w",
        " ",
        "p",
        "a",
        "s",
        "s",
        "w",
        "o",
        "r",
        "d",
        " ",
        "h",
        "a",
        "s",
        " ",
        "b",
        "e",
        "e",
        "n",
        " ",
        "s",
        "a",
        "v",
        "e",
        "d",
        "."
    ]
}
```

Why are all characters returned separated value and wrapped in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

return Response({"detail": force_text(_("New password has been saved."))})
```